# tool for pdf creation from .net?

Tags: c#, html, .net, pdf, creation

We are looking for a sdk to create complex pdf document from a .NET application
So far we used "aspose for pdf" that was Ok appart from the HTML to pdf features
because while generating it crashes depending from the 
complexity/css styles of our html block we add to the pdf (requirement 4)
That why aspose isn't a option for us.
Our mandatory requirements are

1 automatic generation of a table of content (toc) with page information
(not pdf bookmark!)

2 automatic page numbering at the bottom of each page (page x of y)

3 add textual chapter or headings that are 
  references in the toc, 
  important: the chapter numbering 1, 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.1.2 etc. has to be generated automatically !

4 adding html -> pdf elements, the document contains then a mix of a 
    chapter structure, 
    formatted not html text elements, 
    images, 
    html sections

the content and structure of the generated pdf should be like this

```
document title 

<any text> etc.


-- endofpage --

table of content

1 mainchapter  .............. page 1 

1.1 subchapter .............. page 1

2 mainchapter ............... page 3

2.1 subchapter .............. page 3

2.1.1 subchapter ............ page 3

etc. 

-- endofpage --


1 mainchapter <<< chapter number have to be generated automatically depending on the document   structure and actualize if the content or structure changes!

1.1 subchapter

<any text> etc.

<html formated text> <<< any valid html block should be rendered, 
           css styles that can't be interpreted should be ignored 


-- endofpage --

<image>
<any text> etc.

 etc.


-- endofpage --


2 main chapter

<any text> etc.
<image>
<image>
<any text> etc.
```

We didn't find any sdk that offer a automatic chapter numbering  so far
whereas pdfcreator and pdftron offers a stable html rendering, we are missing
any TOC feature from the document heading/chapters.

After 3 days of googling and sample evaluation we didn't find any tool so far.
Does somebody have a hint?

Thank for any idea.
Kagel

Comment: I doubt you didn't find any tool at all. It might be helpful if you state which tools you already dismissed.

Comment: If you have an SDK that allows you to create new pages with formatted text + navigating through the bookmarks, then you can easily write code that generates this TOC that you need.

Answer (score 1):

I've always recommended the following PDF creation libs:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp-LGPL/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/PdfSharp/

Those are two very tested and proven libraries, I believe PdfSharp has the functionality you're looking for

Comment: Hi Nick, pdfsharp was a nice hint at a first glance. Unfortunatly I discovered soon that no html to pdf feature is available or plannes which is a nogo for us, itextsharp was the preceeding sdk before we switch to aspose and was not a alternative, so I keep looking for ...